# Why are my vertical lines not lining up like the horizontal lines in Jetpack Compose for desktop?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I'm learning Kotlin and Jetpack Compose desktop. I've made a Sudoku solver and am now trying to make it graphical. My window dimensions are 800 X 800. I have 20.dp padding around all sides. My formula for placing the horizontal lines works perfect. I would think it would be the same for the vertical lines but they are offset. I found it interesting that the canvas width and height are less than what I declared the window dimensions to be. I played around with the height of the columns and it always drew the line as desired.
[image: puzzle]
[image: Window attributes]

```
@Composable
fun displayPuzzle(answer: Array<Array<IntArray>>) {
    var list = mutableStateListOf<String>()
    for (x in answer[0]) list.addAll(x.map { it.toString() })

    var columnHeighty by remember { mutableStateOf(0F) }
    var columnWidthx by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var pad = 20

    LazyVerticalGrid(

        columns = GridCells.Fixed(9),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(
            start = pad.dp,
            top = pad.dp,
            end = pad.dp,
            bottom = pad.dp
        )

    ) {
        items(list.size) { index ->
            Card(
                backgroundColor = Color.Red,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                        columnWidthx = coordinates.size.width.toFloat()
                        columnHeighty = coordinates.size.height.toFloat()
                    },

                border = BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, color = Color.White)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = list[index],
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 30.sp,
                    color = Color(0xFF000000),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(23.dp)
                )
            }

        }

    }

    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val canvasWidth = size.width
        val canvasHeight = size.height
        val strokeWidth = 5.0F

        println("Canvas Width $canvasWidth")
        println("Canvas Height $canvasHeight")
        println("Column Width $columnWidthx")
        println("Column Height $columnHeighty")

        //Draw 1st vertical separator
        drawLine(
            start = Offset(x = columnWidthx * 3 + pad.toFloat(), y = pad.toFloat()),
            end = Offset(x = columnWidthx * 3 + pad.toFloat(), y = canvasHeight - pad.toFloat()),
            color = Color.Black,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        )
        //Draw 2nd vertical separator
        drawLine(
            start = Offset(x = columnWidthx * 6 + pad.toFloat(), y = pad.toFloat()),
            end = Offset(x = columnWidthx * 6 + pad.toFloat(), y = canvasHeight - pad.toFloat()),
            color = Color.Black,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        )
        //Draw 1st horizontal separator
        drawLine(
            start = Offset(x = pad.toFloat(), y = columnHeighty * 3 + pad.toFloat()),
            end = Offset(x = canvasWidth - pad.toFloat() , y = columnHeighty * 3 + pad.toFloat()),
            color = Color.Black,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        )
        //Draw 2nd horizontal seperator
        drawLine(
            start = Offset(x = pad.toFloat(), y = columnHeighty * 6 + pad.toFloat()),
            end = Offset(x = canvasWidth - pad.toFloat() , y = columnHeighty * 6 + pad.toFloat()),
            color = Color.Black,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        )
        //Draw top border
        drawLine(
            start = Offset(x = pad.toFloat(), y = pad.toFloat() + strokeWidth / 2),
            end = Offset(x = canvasWidth - pad.toFloat() , y = pad.toFloat() + strokeWidth / 2),
            color = Color.Black,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        )
        //Draw bottom border
        drawLine(
            start = Offset(x = pad.toFloat(), y = canvasHeight - pad.toFloat() - strokeWidth / 2),
            end = Offset(x = canvasWidth - pad.toFloat() , y = canvasHeight - pad.toFloat() - strokeWidth / 2),
            color = Color.Black,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        )
        //Draw left border
        drawLine(
            start = Offset(x = pad.toFloat(), y = pad.toFloat()),
            end = Offset(x = pad.toFloat() , y = canvasHeight - pad.toFloat()),
            color = Color.Black,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        )
        //Draw right border
        drawLine(
            start = Offset(x = canvasWidth - pad.toFloat(), y = pad.toFloat()),
            end = Offset(x = canvasWidth - pad.toFloat() , y = canvasHeight - pad.toFloat()),
            color = Color.Black,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidth
        )

    }

}
```

```
   Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        window.minimumSize = Dimension(800,800)
        displayPuzzle(finalAnswer[0])
    }
```

Comment: “the canvas width and height are less than what I declared the window dimensions to be.” — I don't know JetPack, but I suspect the window size have to include the window borders, title bar, etc. as well as your Canvas. (That would be why your canvas is given slightly less height than width, to allow for the title bar.) Can you set a minimum size on your canvas, and let the window work out how much larger it needs to be?

Comment: It is not clear what are columnWidthx and columnHeighty

Comment: Whoops when I made the edit I didn't include all of the function text. They are the width and height of the boxes. @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: You are using `dp` and float in a wrong way. For example define `var pad = 20.dp` and then inside the `Canvas` use: `val pad = density.run { pad.toPx() }`

Comment: I made your changes and it still had the same behaviour. I finally figured out the width of the cells wasn't constant. I used the modifier for .requiredWidth and it's working as desired. Thank you for your help. You showed me better some programming techniques. @GabrieleMariotti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the width of the cells was varying by 1 dp. I used Modifier.requiredWidth and it works as desired.